# How do I make the back button go to the previous page instead of jumping internal links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, my browsers back button is jumping internal links on my website. Each section has an ID, and the navigation jumps to the section with the corresponding ID. I want my website to go back to say, Google, if that is where the user came from, instead of jumping around on my page.

How do I go about doing this? Is there a way to control what the browsers back button does on my website?

Comment: And what if the user on your page just want's to go back to the previous section where he was at by clicking the back button? Just cause that's what I expect by clicking the back button ...

Comment: @caramba That's not their question. I'm sure they understand browser logic.

Comment: @BlakeConnally also just here trying to help. Maybe the questioner did not think about that, that's why I mentioned. Because he is just about to change the normal browser behaviour which in most cases is not good.

Comment: @caramba It is a relatively small one-page website with a fixed navigation. I feel that it is easy enough to navigate without having to press back to jump to previous sections. I am also trying to keep the # hidden in the url's so that the user only sees the "www.site.com" at all times, so if someone presses back, it confusingly jumps on the page instead of returning to their previous page. I hope this clears any confusion you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has been revised to show the correct information. By changing the way the A elements function, it won't add # to the URL, also when they click the back button they will be taken to the page they were on before they visited your site (As long as your site is one page).

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<!--These are your links that will take the user to each part of the page.
Change the value in the onclick function to the name of your div-->
<a href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="goToByScroll('div1')">Click here to go to Div 1</a>
<a href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="goToByScroll('div2')">Click here to go to Div 2</a>

<!--Add ID attributes to your divs, this is what you will put in the goToByScroll Onclick value.-->
<div id="div1" style="margin-top: 700px">
    <!--Div 1 Info-->
Div 1
</div>
<div id="div2" style="margin-top: 700px">
    <!--Div 2 info-->
Div 2
</div>
<!--This is the JS function. I've added in a smooth scrolling technique to make it not choppy.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToByScroll(id){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @caramba That is exactly what this does. Read the questions thoroughly before you comment.

Comment: Hi Blake, I am going to try this answer using PHP after work tomorrow (going to bed now), could you please explain the process on how this code snippet integrates with PHP cookie code? I am not that familiar with the code in the snippet nor a PHP expert, I am still learning. As commented above to caramba, I am trying to hide the # symbols as well in my url, how will this affect the code?

Comment: @envy181 I have revised my answer to fit your question. It was misleading with the first info, this should do the trick. You can run the code snippet to see that it works. It will not add # as well as it will take them back to the page previous to yours.